# I only want styles for an element to change when the ID is used as the selector and not a class name

Tags: html, css, class, select

I have created an extension that creates a div element on that page where it is open. But on a different site, it looks different because the styles are different per that website.

Comment: can you please explain your question and add some code which shows your problem?

Comment: So another site's styling is bleeding over into elements added via your extension. Add a `reset` class to your div, and use any of the many CSS reset libraries out there to reset the div's styling before applying your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset all styles for an element to the default by using `all:unset`. [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) is a shorthand for all properties, and [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) resets the value to the factory default defined for CSS.

Note that this also destroys all useragent styles, so you will have to restore the `display` value back to `block` after using this.

```css
div {          /* example of styles as used on the webpage */
  color: red;
  font: italic 2rem cursive;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is what divs on the page all look like -->
<div>This is a normal div.</div>

<!-- and this is what your div looks like -->
<div style="all:unset; display:block">This is an unsettled div.</div>
```

Warning: currently not compatible with IE and Edge.